# Parallel Execution in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, executors

I have master jenkins with 4 executors. Is it possible to run my build in all the 4 Executor in parallel.
I have tried NodeLabelParameter Plugin. But my build is running in only one executor.(using this plugin I can select any number of node but I have only master node)
I want to know that , How can I run my build in all the 4 executors in parallel?
Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you wan't a single build to run in parallel or four builds to build in parallel?

Comment: Single build in all the four executors in parallel.

Comment: I have tried Throttle concurrent build, I have set Maximum concurrent build per node to 3..still only one build is running..it is not running in parallel.

Comment: Well there is the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin, tells Jenkins that the job in equation is "heavy" and consumes more resources than an ordinary job. With that said it is up to your job script to consume the resources.